# Google Sheet API V4(Java) append Date in cells

Tags: java, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am tried to add date in cells but sheet automatically store value in string with single quote (`'`). For Store value in date , We also try to add `userEnteredFormat` but it didn't work for us.

Below are append request.

```
{
requests = [{
    appendCells = {
        fields = userEnteredValue,
        userEnteredFormat.numberFormat,
        rows = [{
            values = [{
                userEnteredValue = {
                    numberValue = 10.0
                }
            }, {
                userEnteredValue = {
                    stringValue = Sample String
                }
            }, {
                userEnteredFormat = {
                    numberFormat = {
                        type = DATE
                    }
                },
                userEnteredValue = {
                    stringValue = 2015 - 07 - 13
                }
            }, {
                userEnteredValue = {
                    boolValue = true
                }
            }, {
                userEnteredFormat = {
                    numberFormat = {
                        type = DATE
                    }
                },
                userEnteredValue = {
                    stringValue = 2015 - 07 - 13
                }
            }]
        }],
        sheetId = abc
    }
}]}
```

Sample Code to append single date cells on sheet

```
package org.pentaho.googlesheets.api;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.pentaho.di.i18n.BaseMessages;
import org.pentaho.pdi.steps.googlesheets.GoogleSheetsOutputStepMeta;

import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.drive.DriveScopes;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.Sheets;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.SheetsScopes;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.model.AppendCellsRequest;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.model.BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.model.BatchUpdateSpreadsheetResponse;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.model.CellData;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.model.CellFormat;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.model.ExtendedValue;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.model.NumberFormat;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.model.Request;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.model.RowData;

public class DateIssueSample {

    static String APPLICATION_NAME ;
    static JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY;
    static HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT;
    static List<String> SPREADSHEET_SCOPES ;
    static List<String> DRIVE_SCOPES ;
    static Sheets service;

    static String email = "demo-983@praxis-practice-133423.iam.gserviceaccount.com";
    static String pkey ="E:\\P12Key\\My Project-834a8d37d247.p12";

    public static Credential authorize(List<String> SCOPES ) throws Exception {
        GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
        .setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT)
        .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
        .setServiceAccountId(email)
        .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPES)
        .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new java.io.File(pkey))
        .build();
        credential.refreshToken();

        return credential;

    }
    public static  Sheets getSheetsService() throws Exception {
        Credential credential = authorize(SPREADSHEET_SCOPES);
        return new Sheets.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        APPLICATION_NAME = "PDI";
        JSON_FACTORY =new GsonFactory();
        SPREADSHEET_SCOPES =Arrays.asList(SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS);
        DRIVE_SCOPES=Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY);
        HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();

        service = getSheetsService();

        String spreadSheetID= "abc";
        Integer sheetID = 123;
        String DateValue = "2015-07-13";

        List<RowData> rowData = new ArrayList<RowData>();
        List<CellData> cellData = new ArrayList<CellData>();

        CellData cell = new CellData();
        cell.setUserEnteredValue(new ExtendedValue().setStringValue(DateValue));
        cell.setUserEnteredFormat(new CellFormat().setNumberFormat(new NumberFormat().setType("DATE")));

        cellData.add(cell);
        rowData.add(new RowData().setValues(cellData));

        BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest batchRequests = new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();
        BatchUpdateSpreadsheetResponse response;
        List<Request> requests = new ArrayList<Request>();      

        AppendCellsRequest appendCellReq = new AppendCellsRequest();
        appendCellReq.setSheetId( sheetID);
        appendCellReq.setRows( rowData );           
        appendCellReq.setFields("userEnteredValue,userEnteredFormat.numberFormat");


        requests = new ArrayList<Request>();
        requests.add( new Request().setAppendCells(appendCellReq));
        batchRequests = new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();
        batchRequests.setRequests( requests );      


        response=  service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadSheetID, batchRequests).execute();
        System.out.println("Request \n\n");
        System.out.println(batchRequests.toPrettyString());
        System.out.println("\n\nResponse \n\n");
        System.out.println(response.toPrettyString());
    }

}
```

[SpreadSheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i76Ih.png) , 
[Sample Code for Single Date value append](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9v09bytis55sotl/DateIssueSample.java?dl=0)

Comment: The sample request you've shown doesn't seem to include any quotes around the values - are you sure that's *really* the request?

Comment: @JonSkeet : We didn't include any quotes but Google Sheet API automatically include it to consider date as string. Above request is original request to append data mansion on screenshot.

Comment: So why did you remove the quotes from the request when you included it in the question? Basically, it's a lot easier to help you if you either provide the code that generates the request, or the actual request being made. Something that's "a bit like the request" but not actually the same is less helpful.

Comment: @JonSkeet : We didn't add this quote but api automatically take it and make value as  string.  
Above request is original request generated by our code. We only modify sheetID nothing else.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand - that clearly *isn't* the request that is being sent, because that would include quotes. What did you do to get the version you've copied and pasted here?

Comment: We want to append date in sheet's cell but Google Sheet API store value in string with quote(that is not included by us).

Comment: Well, I'd expect the *request* to have quotes because that's how the value is transferred. But I wouldn't expect it to end up in the final sheet. However, while you won't show the *actual* request or the code that produces it, it's very hard to help you. Ideally, provide a [mcve] so that we can reproduce the problem directly.

Comment: Here is sample code for append date value in sheet but Sheet API automatically convert to string value. 

https://www.dropbox.com/s/9v09bytis55sotl/DateIssueSample.java?dl=0

Comment: No, please put the code *in the question* rather than linking to it on Dropbox. All of this is in the service of making this a good question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Right, that's better - although for it to be *complete* (and to make it as easy as possible for others to reproduce the problem) it would be useful to have the import statements as well... the complete code you can just copy and paste into a new file. I'm trying to reproduce the problem now.

Comment: Ok Done @JonSkeet Let us know if you require more information.

Comment: Okay, I've reproduce the issue - now to fix it...

Comment: Can I check - is your ultimate goal to be able to specify the date as text, or are you just trying to get a date in there? Because I've got it working using `setNumberValue()`...

Comment: Our Ultimate go is store date in sheet cell. Thank you @JonSkeet

Comment: @JonSkeet please share your working sample.

Comment: Hi, i am confused about reference of sheetID that is being shown as integer while on excel sheet, sheet name is entered as string. can anyone clarify on it ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To provide an example of what Sam's answer means, if you just want to create a date value using `AppendCellsRequest`, you can create the cell like this:

```
CellData cell = new CellData();
cell.setUserEnteredValue(new ExtendedValue().setNumberValue(42198.0));
cell.setUserEnteredFormat(
    new CellFormat().setNumberFormat(new NumberFormat().setType("DATE")));
```

Here 42198 is the number of days between December 30th 1899 and July 13th 2015.

Comment: We try this code but in sheet date stored as "1466690853849" .. 

String DateValue = "2015-07-13";
  DateTime date = new DateTime(DateValue);     
     Double val = Double.valueOf(date.getValue());
     
  CellData cell = new CellData();
  cell.setUserEnteredValue(new ExtendedValue().setNumberValue(val));
  cell.setUserEnteredFormat(new CellFormat().setNumberFormat(new NumberFormat().setType("DATE")));

Comment: @GauravAshara: Well yes, presumably `DateTime.getValue()` doesn't return "the number of days since December 31st 1899". I don't know which `DateTime` type that is, but that value looks like a "number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch" which isn't the same thing at all.

Comment: We uses google API DateTime 

import com.google.api.client.util.DateTime;

Comment: @GauravAshara: I'd suggest using `java.time` if you can; it'll make it easier to perform date/time arithmetic. But basically, we've now moved the problem from "How do I format a value for sheets" to "How do I get the number of days since December 31st 1899". I suggest you try to solve that, and post a new question if you can't figure it out.

Comment: I've updated the documentation @ https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/concepts#datetime_serial_numbers to correctly say Dec 30 instead of Dec 31.  Thanks @jonskeet for pointing out the problem!

Comment: how.the.hell can I convert normal date, like "20.10.2019" to that integer numberValue?

Comment: @Starwave: Have you read https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts?nav=true#datetime_serial_numbers yet?

Comment: Yes, and I there is 0 mention of any built-in helper class that does that epoch-type conversion automatically. Letting humans do that integer construction manually is a giant flaw. I know I definately would oversee something by crafting it...

Comment: This is the closest code-ready thingy that I found, but still figuring out the 1 day difference issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38015854/java-epoch-date-for-google-spreadsheet

Answer (score 5):

See the [intro guide](https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/concepts?nav=true#datetime_serial_numbers) explanation on how the API works with datetimes.

Dates in Sheets are numbers, not strings. (This lets you, for example, do arithmetic over them.)

If using the ['values' collection](https://developers.google.com/sheets/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values), there's hooks for translating from string to date and vice versa (using different [ValueInputOptions](https://developers.google.com/sheets/reference/rest/v4/ValueInputOption) or [ValueRenderOptions](https://developers.google.com/sheets/reference/rest/v4/ValueRenderOption).

Unfortunately, there's no Append method yet in the values collection. So to easily append cells after existing data, you need to use spreadsheets.batchUpdate, and that's just the raw spreadsheet DOM.  So for now, you'll need to input the dates as the serial numbers (with date formatting), as described in the first link.

The reason the strings are being added with a single quote is because you're telling the API you want to add a string, so a quote is being prefixed to prevent Sheets from accidentally parsing the value into a date.