# Java Epoch Date for Google SpreadSheet

Tags: java, spreadsheet, google-sheets-api, epoch

I tried to add date on Google spreadsheet. To add date we have convert date in epoch.

For Spreadsheet epoch

Google Sheets uses a form of epoch date that is commonly used in spreadsheets. The whole number portion of the value (left of the decimal) counts the days since December 30th 1899. The fractional portion (right of the decimal) counts the time as a fraction of one day. For example, January 1st 1900 at noon would be 2.5, 2 because it's two days after December 30th, 1899, and .5 because noon is half a day. February 1st 1900 at 3pm would be 33.625.

We uses Joda time API for calculation.(Our JDK version 1.7).

For Whole number we uses below code.

```
public static double getEpochDate(Date inputDate)
{

    MutableDateTime epoch = new MutableDateTime();
    epoch.setTime(0, 0, 0, 0);
    epoch.setDate(1899,12,30); //Set to Epoch time
    System.out.println(epoch);
    DateTime now = new DateTime(inputDate);
    Days days = Days.daysBetween(epoch, now);


    return Double.valueOf(days.getDays());
}
```

We are facing issue to find faction part of epoch number

Answer (score 6):

One option would be to take the "milliseconds since the Unix epoch" value (e.g. with `Date.getTime()`), offset that to get "milliseconds since the Sheets epoch" and then perform a floating point division by 24 hours. Something like this:

```
// Precomputed difference between the Unix epoch and the Sheets epoch.
private static final long SHEETS_EPOCH_DIFFERENCE = -2209161600000L;

public static double getEpochDate(Date date)
{
    long millisSinceUnixEpoch = date.getTime();
    long millisSinceSheetsEpoch = millisSinceUnixEpoch - SHEETS_EPOCH_DIFFERENCE;
    return millisSinceSheetsEpoch / (double) TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1);
}
```

No need for Joda Time to get involved in this case. (When you *do* want to use Joda Time, I'd strongly advise avoiding the `Mutable*` types. And only use `DateTime` when there's genuinely a time zone involved...)

Comment: Thank You for very quick reply. All calculation work perfectly if we just remove minus sing from -2209161600000L. Date will be calculated by since 1899 DEC 30th so we have just add from since Unix Epoch.

Comment: @GauravAshara: Or subtract the constant instead of adding it... either way will work, of course. I've changed the answer accordingly.

Comment: Got excited, but then ran into a problem with this in testing: Your function represents the date "05.09.2019" as "43712.875". However, when I feed that number into google sheets cell and transform that cells formatting into date, it shows it as "04.09.2019".

Comment: What *exact* `Date` value was that, in terms of the return value from `Date.getTime()`? My guess is that this is a time zone issue.

Comment: SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
 Date date = format.parse("05.09.2019");

Comment: @Starwave: That depends on your system default time zone, which is why asked about the return value from `Date.getTime()`.

Comment: `millisSinceUnixEpoch` using the date "05.09.2019" returns `1567630800000`

Comment: @Starwave: Right, so that represents 2019-09-04T21:00:00Z. So that explains things. If you parse the text *specifying UTC* then I suspect it'll be fine.

Comment: Following your insight, adding `format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));` did the trick, big thanks!