# How to use Google Java Sheet API V4 to format cells as NUMBER and DATE

Tags: java, google-sheets-api

Greeting,

I'm trying to add formatting to my Google Sheets using the Java API V4.

The following code is my best understanding of what is required to format a series of columns and rows to be of type NUMBER with a single integer digit. Also there is one column with a DATE format. The code does not return any errors buts also does not alter the formatting on my sheet such that eash numeric values and date have a annoying apostrophe in front of each value like '5 and 'Oct 26 2016 13:34. I'm been trying to format the fields in order to remove that apostrophe which the sheet is adding automatically.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
    public static void setProperties(String spreadsheetId, int length) throws IOException {


    List<Request> requests = new ArrayList<>();

    requests.add(new Request()
            .setRepeatCell(new RepeatCellRequest()
                    .setCell(new CellData()
                            .setUserEnteredFormat(new CellFormat().setNumberFormat(new NumberFormat().setPattern("0").setType("NUMBER"))))
                    .setRange(new GridRange()
                            .setSheetId(0)
                            .setStartRowIndex(3)
                            .setEndRowIndex(2 + length)
                            .setStartColumnIndex(3)
                            .setEndColumnIndex(22))
                    .setFields("userEnteredFormat.numberFormat")
            ));
    requests.add(new Request()
            .setRepeatCell(new RepeatCellRequest()
                    .setCell(new CellData()
                            .setUserEnteredFormat(new CellFormat().setNumberFormat(new NumberFormat().setPattern("0").setType("NUMBER"))))
                    .setRange(new GridRange()
                            .setSheetId(0)
                            .setStartRowIndex(3)
                            .setEndRowIndex(2 + length)
                            .setStartColumnIndex(24)
                            .setEndColumnIndex(24))
                    .setFields("userEnteredFormat.numberFormat")
            ));
    requests.add(new Request()
            .setRepeatCell(new RepeatCellRequest()
                    .setCell(new CellData()
                            .setUserEnteredFormat(new CellFormat().setNumberFormat(new NumberFormat().setPattern("mmm dd yyyy hh+:mm").setType("DATE"))))
                    .setRange(new GridRange()
                            .setSheetId(0)
                            .setStartRowIndex(3)
                            .setEndRowIndex(2 + length)
                            .setStartColumnIndex(23)
                            .setEndColumnIndex(23))
                    .setFields("userEnteredFormat.numberFormat")
            ));

    BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest batchUpdateRequest = new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest()
            .setRequests(requests);
    SHEETS.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId, batchUpdateRequest)
            .execute();
}




    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-sheets</artifactId>
        <version>v4-rev21-1.22.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Thanks,
Conteh

Comment: Not sure if this helps but have you checked the Date and [Number Formats guide](https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/formats) for Sheets API?

Comment: Yes,, I reviewed that document while developing the code. I believe the patterns are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this question [Google Sheet API V4(Java) append Date in cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37986171/google-sheet-api-v4java-append-date-in-cells), where a similar issue is reported.

Additionally, I've used Google Sheet API V3 and  Google Sheet API V4 that issue is not present in v3.

Comment: Thanks, Yeah the problem stemmed from my declarations of the types. I had declared String arrays for the arrays of numeric data because I wasn't doing a calculation on that data. There were just rankings between 1-5. When I changed the type from a String array to an Integer array then the apostrophe went away. Similarly the date I had converted into a formatted string in the code prior to the addition or code to set the pattern. If I just load up the date type, then the apostrophe is removed.

Comment: I was getting similar issues with Date types, when I was using the v4, but for the project purposes I had to roll back to v3, which coincidentally got rid of the apostrophe issue I was having. I'll keep that in mind if I have to use the library again.