# insertRow of python in Google sheets api

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

I am doing insert to a google sheet with insertRow :

```py
veri["date"] = date_day + " " + date_month + " " + date_year
ekle = [veri["date"]]
sheet.insert_row(ekle, 3)
```

`date_day`, `date_month` and `date_year` is string format.

The operation completes successfully, but appends " ' " to the beginning of my date and Excel doesn't understand my date.
Excel understands that my date is string.
It understands the date format when there is no " ' " in Excel.

for example :

```py
veri["date"]  = "02 eylül 2021"
sheet.insert_row(veri["date"], 3)
```

I checking excel output: `'02 eylül 2021`
This " ' " not seen in cell but appears in the text bar.

(syntax is not important for now. I hope you understand my problem).

Thank you now.

Excel output:

[image: excel output]

[this is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37986171/google-sheet-api-v4java-append-date-in-cells) like my problem but from java.

Comment: I am having difficultly figuring out what the question is. Are you inserting in Excel or Google Sheets? Is the problem, you would like to insert a string into Google Sheets but it is being treated like a date?

Comment: i am inserting in google sheets a string cell. but it is not being treated like a date. adds " ' " to the beginning of the string like screenshot ( '02 Eylül 2021 ). my string is "02 Eylül 2021" but api is inserting to be "'02 Eylül 2021". what is " ' ", where is from. why is from?